# cakephp multiple records data array fit in request data

Tags: arrays, cakephp, view, model, request

I need to get multiple records from model, then put them into request->data for a view to render into a form with multiple input fieldsets for example name='data[Applicant][0][display_name]'. name='data[Applicant][1][display_name]'...data value goes in for each applicant.

Actually I've already done what i want, but i do not think it is a good method to do so. 
Appreciate if anyone can guide me

```
        foreach ($this->Applicant->data['Applicant'] as $key=>$item){
            $data['Applicant'][] = $item['Applicant'];
        }
        $this->request->data = $data;//set Model to data
        $this->set('data' , $this->Applicant->data);
```

$this->Applicant->data is the following:

```
    Array
(
    [Applicant] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Applicant] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [application_id] => 17
                            [name] => User
                            [first_name] =>
...
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Applicant] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [application_id] => 17
                        [name] => 
                        [first_name] =>
```

the following is the desired output (less one level):

```
Array
(
    [Applicant] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [application_id] => 17
                    [name] => User
                    [first_name] => 
...

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [application_id] => 17
                    [name] => 
                    [first_name] =>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should suffice:

```
$this->request->data['Applicant'] = Hash::extract( $this->Applicant->data, 'Applicant.{n}.Applicant' );
```